# Forcing Haskell Stack to be Version 1.7.* on NixOS

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nixos

**Context.**

1. I'm running NixOS, with `stack` included in my `configuration.nix`.
2. Running `stack --version` yields `Version 1.6.3 x86_64`.
3. But I need Version `>=1.7` in order to compile a bleeding edge Haskell package that my team is working on.
4. The current version on nixpkgs search is `1.6.5`, which is too old anyway.
5. I think normally on non-NixOS you could just run "stack upgrade" in your home folder, but that doesn't seem to work.

**Question:** Does anyone know how to force stack on NixOS to compile to version, i.e., `1.7.1`?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this overlay should do the trick:

```
(self: super: {
  haskellPackages = super.haskellPackages.extend
    (hself: hsuper: {
      stack = (hsuper.callHackage "stack" "1.7.1" {})
              .overrideScope (hself2: hsuper2: {
        Cabal = hself2.Cabal_2_2_0_1;
        hpack = hself2.hpack_0_28_2;
      });
    });
})
```

This successfully builds `stack` on Nixpkgs master. It will be available as the `stack` attribute or `haskellPackages.stack` attribute.

Comment: I get the error "attribute 'Cabal_2_2_0_1' missing" when building.

Comment: Also I've modified it to stack version "1.8.0" (the new bleeding edge from `stack update --git`), and I'm getting "tar: */stack/1.8.0/stack.json: Not found in archive".

Comment: You may need a newer version of Nixpkgs, because even the `callHackage` versions are pinned by Nixpkgs. If it doesn't resolve the missing Cabal attribute error, you may be able to find the right version of the Cabal library using `nix repl`.